# DRY up common-case require in TypeScript under NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

If most of the time I'm going to be writing:

```
const FOO = require('FOO');
```

I don't want to be writing FOO twice.

Something like

```
function r(moduleName) {
    var name = require('path').parse(moduleName).name;
    return "const " + name + " = require(\"" + moduleName + "\");";
} //once
```

coupled with:

```
eval(r('FOO'));
```

seems to DRY up the code beautifully in JS.

Can I do something similar in TypeScript?

The problem with the `eval` is that it hides the var declaration from `TypeScript` so I would need to add

```
declare var FOO;
```

But having to do that defeats the purpose of the `eval` macro.

Comment: So instead of having to write `FOO` twice, you're now writing `eval(r(...))` for each module you want to import? How is that not DRY? It seems a bit bikesheddy to me.

Comment: `const FOO = require('FOO');` isn't DRY. `eval(r('FOO'));` is.

Comment: `const foo = require('FOO')` would also solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do something similar in TypeScript?

No. There are is no *type system* macro support at the moment.